# Could not load file or assembly 'B.DLL' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-7

Along with: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format

I have A.EXE that references B.DLL. Both are mine. Both are set to x86 for the platform target. B.DLL references:

```
System
System.Data
System.Windows.Forms
System.XML
```

I am using VS2010 on Win7 64-bit. All search results I can find say that this is because of loading 32-bit assemblies into 64-bit executables or vice versa. However I have checked and rechecked that A.EXE and B.DLL are set to use "x86" as the platform target. I've also tried cleaning and rebuilding the entire solution. B.DLL builds with no errors or warnings.

This is a previously working project. I'm currently working on refactoring it by moving some code out of A.EXE an into the newly-created B.DLL.

I tried setting A.EXE to "Any CPU" and it didn't help (I didn't expect it to). Changing it back to "x86" didn't help either.

I am targeting .NET 3.5

**Update**

I created a new C# class library C.DLL and added a reference to B.DLL. C.DLL is set to x86 and it compiles fine.

**Update**

The compile-time error occurs in MainForm.resx at a closing "data" tag:

```
  <data name="StatusStripImages.ImageStream"
  mimetype="application/x-microsoft.net.object.binary.base64">
    <value>
    ...
    </value>
  </data>
```

**Update**

I now suspect resgen.exe. I tried forcing it to be 32-bit and I broke it (see: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vseditorprerelease/thread/6782c692-a9b6-4930-a099-4ee4092e91a9).

Any ideas?

thanks, Andy

Comment: The error message points to an embedded image in a .resx resource file. I tried remove it and the error just moved to a different embedded image.

Comment: Most everybody has been working from the assumption that this was a runtime problem.  Looks like this is actually a *build* problem.  Document details about what is in your project, stuff like .res files and reference assemblies.

Comment: A.EXE was working fine. All I did was move some classes into a new assembly, B.DLL then added a reference to it. In reality the project is quite large. I am hoping for pointers on where to look so I can continue with web searches, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I am suffering from a bug [1] in Visual Studio 2010 that Microsoft can't be bothered to fix even though they've known about it for months.

There are three workarounds and I just changed A.EXE and B.DLL from .NET 3.5 to .NET 4.0 to solve it. Not ideal but I didn't want to make changes to resgen.exe. I guess I have to wait for SP1 to be able to target .NET 3.5.

[1] http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/06/19/resgen-exe-error-an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-an-incorrect-format.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can verify if the 32bit flag is correctly set on both assemblies by running "corflags" against them.

Comment: I can't check A.EXE as it won't build. B.DLL gives: Version   : v2.0.50727
CLR Header: 2.5
PE        : PE32
CorFlags  : 3
ILONLY    : 1
32BIT     : 1
Signed    : 0

Answer (score 1):

Generally the exception BadFormatException occurs when a dll is built in x86 is tried to be loaded in x64 application.

In your project properties Recheck if the Platform Target is set both either to x86 or to x64. Mixing up both creates an issue.

Comment: Yes, I know. I've checked and rechecked because I knew from past experience that it is a cause of this problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are not a lot of a failure modes here.  But *do* keep in mind that the Target Platform setting is *separate* for the Debug and the Release version.  And that the configuration name in VS2010 doesn't actually have anything to do with the Target Platform setting.  In other words, you can change the Target Platform but it will still be named "x86" in Build + Configuration Manager.  Tricky.

So double-check your assumptions.  Actually verify the Target Platform combo for *both* configurations.  And Bob's recommendation to triple-check with Corflags.exe is a good idea.  Run it from the Visual Studio Command prompt.  Only the EXE setting matters, the DLLs have to follow suit with what the startup assembly demanded.  There are additional failure modes if your code gets started by other means than a EXE.  Like a unit-test runner.

Comment: I am looking at the "Platform Target" under the project properties for each project.

Comment: Only the setting for the EXE project matters, keep the DLLs at Any CPU.

Comment: The projects are set to x86 for both Debug and Release. Both fail to build in the same way.

Comment: Whoa, "failed to build" is another kettle of fish.  Everybody has been assuming runtime problems.  That is a (unusual) reference assembly problem.  Shouldn't happen, are you referencing COM components in your project?

Comment: No COM components. B.DLL does use P/Invoke to a 32-bit C-based DLL. That's why my whole project needs to be 32-bit.

Answer (score 1):

FIX

I was suffering from the exact issue described by the current accepted answer for this question that points to the link below

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2010/06/19/resgen-exe-error-an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-an-incorrect-format.aspx

However, after eading this:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/532584/error-when-compiling-resx-file-seems-related-to-beta2-bug-5252020

It appears that if you open the failing .resx file you will a line similar to

```
<data name="imageList1.ImageStream" mimetype="application/x-microsoft.net.object.binary.base64">
```

There is a block of data within this element. The first line reads

```
AAEAAAD/////AQAAAAAAAAAMAgAAAFdTeXN0ZW0uV2luZG93cy5Gb3JtcywgVmVyc2lvbj00LjAuMC4w
```

Simply replace last **0** with a **y** making the line read

```
AAEAAAD/////AQAAAAAAAAAMAgAAAFdTeXN0ZW0uV2luZG93cy5Gb3JtcywgVmVyc2lvbj0yLjAuMC4w
```

This worked for me straight away. I like how it spells out **j0y**. Not a great fix but it's the best I've seen short of a fix.

**j0y**,

----Nanook